# Does validating a deployment impact application performance?

Tags: deployment, change-set

Earlier today, I was using Copado to validate a change set to UAT sandbox that included ~40 apex classes and running code coverage for all of them.  Within the same 30 minute time period that the validation was running, users testing an application in the target sandbox that uses a lot of the classes in the change set reported a four minute delay in triggers firing.  Does validating a deployment impact custom application performance in the target org?

Comment: So, they clicked a save button and it look 4+ minutes to save? Triggers aren't specifically "delayed", they're synchronous, so the description of the problem sounds faulty. Can you please clarify?

Comment: The trigger, as well as several classes included in the deployment, were part of the deployment.  My question (on behalf of my customer), is whether the deployment would have caused the delay the UAT folks reported.  I don't believe it will, but I don't know how to disprove this.  The timing may have been purely coincidental.

Comment: deployment process locks write-access to resources getting deployed until deployment completes but that does not impact performance and as Brian said your trigger definition is different from how the trigger works in the Salesforce environment. do you mean any callouts?